# How to share complex java objects across views servlets methods within a spring controller without making those objects singleton bean?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

It's as simple. In Spring MVC, how and where do I store a complex java object so that it is available across the action servlets. For example if an ajax is called on next page, the business object from within some previously called servlet, stored somewhere should be accessible in that ajax action method in java. I did this by creating a singleton bean but it failed when multiple users hit the application. User outputs are affected among each other. I need to achieve this in a non-singleton manner.

Comment: instead of creating a singleton object, you can define `static singleton attributes` of that bean. That singleton attributes should be valid for all users, the rest of the attributes will be specific to the user who is firing the ajax action.

Answer (score 1):

You can store objects in your request object:

> request.setAttribute("key", valueObject);

To get the object, simply use

> request.getAttribute("key");

Or, as Subir Kumar Sao said in the comments, use the session to store your stuff:

> request.getSession().setAttribute("key", valueObject);

and

> request.getSession().getAttribute("key");

Comment: Or session depending upon requirement.

Comment: @s3b I think current page request is destroyed when the response (jsp view in my case) is returned after submit. I guess you are pointing to forward. A different case.

Comment: @user2918640 then try to store the object in the session, like Subir Kumar Sao mentioned.

Comment: It should be `session.setAttribute` and `session.getAttribute`

Comment: Depends on how many users are using your site. And how big your objects are. I wouldn't worry about that now in this case.

Comment: The object is a big one. It's a list of complex objects. And 100 users could be using the application at a time. I don't feel session should be used in such a case. Would like to know some design uplifting though.

Comment: There seems to be a design problem with your application if 100 users each get a "big object" which is too big to get stored in a session. You should reconsider your approach, maybe reading some book about web applications or look into some open source apps which are similar to your project.

Comment: Updated my question to make the problem easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
request.setAttribute("key", valueObject); 
request.getAttribute("key");
```

or

```
session.setAttribute("key", valueObject); 
session.getAttribute("key");
```

Difference between them : **Request-scoped** attribute is visible only while current request is processed. **Session-scoped** attribute is persistent between several requests from the same user.

Comment: Updated my question to make the problem easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your objects on session level. As long as the session is alive, you can access your session level variables, regardless of the requests.

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("key");

request.getSession().getAttribute("key", value);
```

Keep in my mind that once a session level attribute is set, that is always there until, session is killed or invalidated. So you may need to remove the attribute according to your logic.

```
request.getSession().removeAttribute("key");
```

Comment: Updated my question to make it easy to understand.